# Trying to log object keeps returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object

So I have this custom type:

```
export default interface ObjectType {
  size?: number,
  title: string,
  max: number 
}
```

Then I want to inject the above into another custom type,

```
import ObjectType from 'types/objectName'
```

```
export interface NavProps { object?: ObjectType }
```

Then I want to pass the NavProps into my NavComponent to render. So just to make sure things are working I made a small function in my NavComponent file. With NavProps being imported as well

```
export default function NavComponent({object}: NavProps){
    console.log({object})
}
```

I just wanted to console the object so I can see if its properties are passing, but I keep getting undefined. Can anyone assist and explain why this doesnt work? The project is built with Next/React using typescript. Apologies for the format, my cpu died and Im on my phone.

Comment: Are you passing the `object` prop to your nav component?

Comment: Yes above I just edited FootNavProps with what should've been NavProps. Apologies.

Comment: The type has nothing to do with getting undefined. As long as you're passing in the prop, you'll see it in the logs, eg `<NavComponent object="anything" />`